# Combining Int-tel-input with Input masking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I am having an issue combining Int-tel-input (Country code telephone number selector plugin) with input masking.

What I am trying to accomplish here is to allow a user to select a country code from the country dropdown provided by the Int-tel-input plugin and then apply a mask over that to ensure that the user conforms to the number format.

Here is my current implementation (coffeescript):

```
//When a country flag is clicked
$(document).on 'click', '.country', ->
 //Get the country code
 code = "+" + $(this).data('dial-code')
 //Find the input
 elem = $(this).parents(".intl-tel-input").find("input")
 //Clear the input
 $(elem).val("")
 //Mask input with country code
 $(elem).inputmask({
   mask: (code)+"99 999-9999",
   clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
 });
 //Clear masked input to ensure mask is clear
 $(elem).val("")
```

The issue I am running into is that if the country code contains a 9 the masking plugin will replace that character in the country code with a masking space. Example:

I want the input to look like : +394 **-_**-____

The result I am getting looks like : +3_4 **-_**-___

Note: The above implementation works perfectly with country codes which do not contain a 9.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I'm facing the same situation ^^'

Comment: @NateB. Unfortunately not. Ended up changing designs for the product to work around this issue. It's a tricky one!